# Angular an obj is lost upon page reload

Tags: angular, undefined, angular7, lifecycle

I have a service layer that gets a list of users from an API.
Then I list these users on a component and I have a layout to edit with another component.

The obj I've selected from the list stays until I reload the page.

If I follow the workflow (click on users on nav-> get the list component-> click on user-> get to user edit page with a form where details are filled in from the **selectedUser** obj) so everything works well, until i reload the page, then the obj becomes undefined.

**service:**

```
export class UserManagementService {

  selectedUser: User;
  private usersList: UserListDTO[];
  statusOptions: [{}, {}];
  password: string;
  passwordAgain: string;

  constructor(private userResoService: UserResourceService) {
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.usersList = [];
    this.userResoService.findPrivilegedUsersUsingGET().subscribe(resp => {
      resp.forEach(user => this.usersList.push(user));
    });
    this.setStatusOptions();
  }

  getUsersList(): UserListDTO[] {
    return this.usersList;
  }

  getUserById(id: string) {
    this.usersList.filter(user => {
      if (user.id === id) {
        console.log(user);
        this.selectedUser = user;
      }
    });
  }
```

**list-component:**

```
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {

  cols: any[];
  constructor(private userService: UserManagementService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers();
    this.cols = [
      { field: 'firstName', header: 'First Name' },
      { field: 'lastName', header: 'Last Name' },
      { field: 'email', header: 'Email' },
      { field: 'status', header: 'Status' }
    ];
  }

  private navigateToUserEdit() {
    const id = this.userService.selectedUser['id'];
    this.router.navigate(['edit', id], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  onRowSelect(event) {
    this.userService.selectedUser = event['data'];
    this.navigateToUserEdit();
  }

  deleteUser(user) {
    this.userService.selectedUser = user;
  }
}
```

**user-edit-component:**

```
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserManagementService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  userToEdit: {} = {};
  userId: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers();
    this.userService.getUsersList();
    this.getUserIdFromParams();
    this.userService.getUserById(this.userId);
    this.userToEdit = this.userService.selectedUser;
  }

  getUserIdFromParams() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.userId = params.get('userId');
    });
  }
}
```

I've tried to hook the last component up, so it also fetches the list of users then it grabs the user by ID which is from the URL. But that returns undefined as well after reload.

Why does my selected user gets "destroyed" and how can I fix this issue.
I can't fiddle with server side stuff(nor angular under-the-hood behavior) since it's an ongoing project.

Is this some working as intended behavior? If yes how can this be bypassed?

Answer (score 0):

Do your HTTP calls succeed after a page reload? Maybe you have introduced a race condition. Try putting your code into the paramMap subscription:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.userId = params.get('userId');

      this.userService.getUsers();
      this.userService.getUsersList();
      this.getUserIdFromParams();
      this.userService.getUserById(this.userId);
      this.userToEdit = this.userService.selectedUser;
    });
  }
```

EDIT:
Keep in mind that everything is asynchrounous.
1. Get the id parameter from your paramMap (wait for it until it's there)
2. With the id, fetch the stuff from your server (wait until it returned)
3. Display the return value.
So, the code in your component should look something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    map(paramMap => paramMap.get('userId')),
    switchMap(id => this.userService.getUser(id)),
    catchError(() => /* error handling */)
  ).subscribe(user => this.user = user);
}
```

And in your service it should look like:

```
getUser(id: number) {
  this.userResoService.findPrivilegedUsersUsingGET().pipe(
    map((users => users.find(user => user.id === id))
  )
}
```

Comment: On chrome devtools the resuests respond with 200 so yeah. I don't know what's the issue here.

Comment: In that case, I'm pretty sure it's a race condition. You try to fetch the user from your service before the call has returned from your server. You can easily test that by putting your component's initialization code into a big enough `setTimeout`. If that works, that was indeed the case. The best way to tackle these situations is to wrap your entities (`User` in this case) into Observables. Then you don't have to manually set and update the properties as you do now, with Angular's `async` operator you get this out-of-the-box.

Comment: The issue is more likely my logic error.
I've instantiated the list in the service so both of my components can access it, however upon reload i think the service gets rebuilt and lose it's instantiated objects as well b/c i am not calling the service to fetch users and make a list out of it. If I do so no error is shown but i can't iterate through the list. However if I skip the fetch from ngOnInit it gives an error for example forEach since it can't call it upon undefined. But i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @AlexBene I updated the answer, see if that suits you.